# My Vscode always auto open new terminal window when I open it , how can I close this action?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Vscode always auto open new terminal window  when I open it , how can I  close this action?

vscode version:
版本: 1.67.0-insider
提交: 57fd6d0195bb9b9d1b49f6da5db789060795de47
日期: 2022-05-04T12:09:01.690Z
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.4.0

Comment: Do you mean the integrated terminal? One that appears on pressing `CTRL` + `backtick`.

Comment: The most likely culprit is some automated message or response sent to your terminal, possibly by your OS. Geez, your using Darwin? I forget exactly what Darwin is, but from what I remember its like a BSD / OSX hybrid or something of the sort ya??

Comment: Anyways... are you getting a message in the terminal when it opens, or does it just open to the prompt. And does the terminal open each time you click **[FILE]** -> **[NEW WINDOW]** or when you open vscode from the desktop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.